# how to append option text to a list in jquery

Tags: jquery, appendto

I have a tried a few things to get this to work with no luck. I have a select box with a button next to it.  When the button is clicked, the text from the currently selected item needs to be placed inside li tags and appended to a ul inside another div.

```
<!--select box-->
<div class="select-div">
<select id="select-pub">
<option value="1">Publisher 1</option>
<option value="2">Publisher 2</option>
<option value="3">Publisher 3</option>
<option value="4">Publisher 4</option>
</select>
</div> 

<!--this button needs to append the currently selected text to a list-->

<div class="link-div">
<a class="add-button" href="#" style="width:46px;height:22px;display:block;"></a>
</div>

<!--the option text must now populate this unordered list-->

<div id="publisher-results">
<ul>
</ul>
</div>
```

I started here, but how can I get the text within li tags and append that to the ul?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$('.add-button').click(function() {

   $('#publisher-results ul').append($('#select-pub :selected').text());
   });
</script>
```

Any ideas? I've been failing at this all afternoon!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `<li>` set the text and append it like this:

```
$('.add-button').click(function() {
  $('<li />', { text: $('#select-pub :selected').text() })
     .appendTo('#publisher-results ul');
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/y74HN/), this uses the [`$(html, props)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) construction method then uses [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) to place it inside the `<ul>`, it's broken onto 2 lines just to prevent scrolling on SO, it need not be broken up in your code.

Comment: For some reason I am getting li's with no text in them. I'm using this in a modal window and it's just dumping blank li's...I am using your code exactly...any help is appreciated...it's at www.jontakiff.com/list-append/overlay.html